# Using interactive inputs to Create Fishnet using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, vector-grid

I'm creating a fully automatic tool in ModelBuilder, and have a problem with the **Fishnet** function.

The tool should work with different files, and the user only needs to choose a specific txt file (and choose the workspace) to start the process.

For this reason, I need the tool to be be able to create a fishnet extracting all the settings autonomously.
At the moment, the fishnet can extract: *The Template Extent*, the *Cell size Width*, the *Cell size Height* and the *output feature class*.

The problems are the *Fishnet Origin Coordinates* and the *Y-axis Coordinate*. In the common use of the Fishnet instrument, you just need to put the Template Extent and all these fields compiles automatically, but that doesn't happen here.

Comment: Can you extract the Origin from the input FC, minX, minY of the FC extent?

Comment: maybe, I thought about it, but i couldn't to enter the data in the fields. I'll try again.